# SELECT...FOR UPDATE with prepared statement is not working

Tags: php, transactions, mysqli, prepared-statement, table-locking

I am trying to create a fb-like-button function(not facebook api). 
There are two buttons on my website: like and dislike.
Database will save how many likes and dislike in total.

Here is the db table:

```
id |post_id |like_count
40 |     20 |         0
```

code for when user click like button:

```
$id = 40;
$conn->autocommit(FALSE);
$conn->query("BEGIN;");

//lock the row to prevent race condition
$sql = "SELECT like_count FROM post_like WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();

//update the table
$sql = "UPDATE post_like SET like_count = like_count + 1 WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();

$conn->commit();
$conn->autocommit(TRUE);
$conn->close();
//when success, display unlike button to user throught AJAX
```

and code for when user click unlike button:

```
$id = 40;
$conn->autocommit(FALSE);
$conn->query("BEGIN;");

//lock the row to prevent race condition
$sql = "SELECT like_count FROM post_like WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();

//update the table
$sql = "UPDATE post_like SET like_count = like_count - 1 WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();

$conn->commit();
$conn->autocommit(TRUE);
$conn->close();
//when success, display like button to user throught AJAX
```

here is the problem...
number of like_count starts at 0. 
Theoretically, if there is only one person click the button, like_count will not exceed 1 or less than 0.
(click like button->->lock row->like_count+1->release row->display unlike button) 
(click unlike button->lock row->like_count-1->release row->display like button) 
I get this work right when I click the button slowly, however, when I keep on clicking the button quickly, number of like_count can exceed 2, and sometimes it can be a negative number.
I have no clue what I have done wrong. Please help!

Comment: for the last update, why execute is before bind_param?

Comment: Let me ask you a question. What's wrong with race condition here?

Answer (score 0):

in your update query
put

```
$stmt->execute();
```

below

```
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
```

Comment: yes, execute(); is below bind_param in the code im working with, just a mistake posting the code here, this is my first post, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

The code to handle **all** the buttons.

```
$amount = (isset($_POST['like'])) ? 1 : -1;
$sql    = "UPDATE post_like SET like_count = like_count + ? WHERE post_id = ?";
$stmt   = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($amount,$_POST['id']));
```

note that you don't need an id column in this table. post_id is all right

Comment: this code is not intended to solve whatever your problem, mind you. it is the right code to handle your button on the PHP side. While regarding your particular problem, you have to find out first, what is the problem you have

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$conn->autocommit(FALSE);
```

To:

```
$conn->autocommit(TRUE);
```

update and insert query doesn't work with `$conn->autocommit(FALSE);`